# Inverting ill-conditioned matrix in NumPy

Tags: python, numpy, matrix, inverse, rounding-error

I am trying to invert a covariance matrix to calculate a Mahalanobis-distance. However, my covariance matrix is very ill-conditioned (condition number > 10^17). This apparently leads to large rounding errors, resulting in a "matrix inverse" that actually does not have much to do with the real inverse.

My code is:

```
sample = np.array([[523.77, 468.3, 491.55], [234.96, 221.17, 228.43], [342.02, 337.87, 351.31]], np.float64)

print "Sample:"
print sample
print
print "Sample Inverse:"
print np.linalg.inv(sample)
print
print "Sample x Sample Inverse:"
print np.dot(sample, np.linalg.inv(sample))
print
print
print "Cov(Sample):"
print np.cov(sample)
print "Determinant", np.linalg.det(np.cov(sample))
print "Condition Number", np.linalg.cond(np.cov(sample))
print
print "Cov(Sample) Inverse:"
print np.linalg.inv(np.cov(sample))
print
print "Cov(Sample) x Cov(Sample) Inverse:"
print np.dot(np.cov(sample), np.linalg.inv(np.cov(sample)))
```

Which gives the following result:

```
Sample:
[[ 523.77  468.3   491.55]
 [ 234.96  221.17  228.43]
 [ 342.02  337.87  351.31]]

Sample Inverse:
[[ 0.01204863  0.03620989 -0.04040286]
 [-0.10240561  0.36837033 -0.09623795]
 [ 0.08675788 -0.38953001  0.13473714]]

Sample x Sample Inverse:
[[  1.00000000e+00   0.00000000e+00   0.00000000e+00]
 [  3.55271368e-15   1.00000000e+00   3.55271368e-15]
 [  0.00000000e+00   0.00000000e+00   1.00000000e+00]]
# This is obviously fine


Cov(Sample):
[[ 775.9353      190.68715      40.55945   ]
 [ 190.68715      47.58543333   15.68986667]
 [  40.55945      15.68986667   47.36003333]]
Determinant -1.3802775949e-10
Condition Number 3.45634882629e+17

Cov(Sample) Inverse:
[[ -1.45440004e+13   6.08180372e+13  -7.69277831e+12]
 [  6.08180372e+13  -2.54320238e+14   3.21685688e+13]
 [ -7.69277831e+12   3.21685688e+13  -4.06895190e+12]]

Cov(Sample) x Cov(Sample) Inverse:
[[-0.9375    -1.         0.09375  ]
 [-0.4375    -0.125      0.1953125]
 [ 0.        -0.25       1.0625   ]]
# This is wrong
```

which is obviously not what I want...

In reality, my covariance matrix is also not a 3x3, but rather a 145x145 matrix, which makes things worse: The condition number is now larger than 10^18, and numpy.linalg.det() returns 0 for the determinant (which would mean that no inverse exists).

Any suggestions how this problem might be fixed are very much appreciated. Thanks in advance for all your efforts! :)

Answer (score 0):

The rank of the covariant matrix is <= n-1, so the covariant matrix of a square matrix will always be singular. This is part of the nature of covariant matrices (see https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/60622/why-is-a-sample-covariance-matrix-singular-when-sample-size-is-less-than-number)

So although in the example given numpy has given a non-zero value for the determinant, this is due to rounding errors in the use of floats.

So, what you are trying to do is not mathematically sensible. If you have two variables and two observations you have a scatter graph with only two points, and it is certain that the covariance is zero. If we are then trying to calculate Mahalanobis-distance we hit a problem. If a point is not on the line of best fit, it is certainly not part of the distribution (since the covariance is zero) making the Mahalanobis distance infinite...

This is the problem you are finding. So you either need to start with more observations than variables (a non square matrix) or rethink what you are trying to do.