# Product of matrix and its inverse

Tags: python, numpy

How to find the correct code so that product of matrix and its inverse is an identity?

```py
import numpy as np


V = np.array([[1.00000000e+00 ,2.12250279e-03, 1.06273608e-01, 1.00000000e+00],
              [2.12250279e-03 ,1.00000000e+00, 3.01468295e-04, 1.00000000e+00],
              [1.06273608e-01, 3.01468295e-04, 1.00000000e+00, 1.00000000e+00]]
             )

t = np.dot(V.T, V)

invv = np.linalg.inv(t)

final = np.dot(t, invv)

print(final)
```

Comment: What problem do you observe?

Comment: your question is not clear, what I understand here is that you are 
1. Multiplying matrix V with its transpose, 2. getting inverse of matrix t, 3. multiplying t with its inverse

Comment: When I run the code, I get a `final` result that doesn't resemble _a 2-D array with ones on the diagonal and zeros elsewhere_, which is an obvious problem given the supposed working of `np.linalg.inv()`.

Comment: @Armali Yes that is the issue I am trying to clear that why the final matrix is not Identity. How to rectify the code?

Comment: @ElSheikh Yes after the 3rd step the final matrix should be Identity according to mathematics, but I am not getting that. Please suggest some ways to rectify it.

Comment: Yes what are you saying is correct, however, do you know about matrix singularity?

Comment: @ElSheikh Yes, The matrix whose det=0. But the det of matrix 't' here is not 0

Comment: _How to rectify the code?_ I'm afraid the fault is not with the code, but with the data.

Comment: @SmitLunagariya Yes and it has to be invertible as well, which is not the case here, please note that your code is perfectly fine, however your matrix is singular

Comment: _The matrix whose det=0. But the det of matrix 't' here is not 0_ - I now think it actually is; see my expanded answer.

Answer (score 3):

Your example results in a "`numpy.linalg.linalg.LinAlgError`: Singular matrix", because it is not invertible.

Your matrix `t` is [singular](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Invertible_matrix)

Comment: You must be right with the matrix being singular, only it's `t`, not `V`.

Comment: @Armali you are right, edited

Answer (score 1):

The matrix `t` is ill-conditioned (on my system, `np.linalg.cond(t)` returns
91285041857508064.0). See for example [Inverting ill-conditioned matrix in NumPy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26152388/inverting-ill-conditioned-matrix-in-numpy) or also [Does a tiny determinant imply ill-conditioning of a matrix?](https://scicomp.stackexchange.com/questions/1329/does-a-tiny-determinant-imply-ill-conditioning-of-a-matrix)

#### Correction

The closer I look at the matter, the more I'm convinced that the to-be-inverted matrix `t` is not only ill-conditioned, but indeed singular. If I replace `1.06273608e-01` by `x`, `2.12250279e-03` by `y` and `3.01468295e-04` by `z` for the sake of brevity, the determinant of `t` becomes

```
(2*x + y*z)*((x*z + 2*y)*(3*x*y + 6*z - (x + z + 1)*(y + z + 1)) + ((2*x + y*z)*(y + z + 1) - (x*y + 2*z)*(x + y + 1))*(y + z + 1) + (6*x + 3*y*z - (x + y + 1)*(x + z + 1))*(-y**2 - z**2 - 1)) + (-x*z - 2*y)*((-x*y - 2*z)*(6*x + 3*y*z - (x + y + 1)*(x + z + 1)) + (x*z + 2*y)*(3*x**2 + 3*z**2 - (x + z + 1)**2 + 3) + ((2*x + y*z)*(x + z + 1) - (x + y + 1)*(x**2 + z**2 + 1))*(y + z + 1)) + (-x - y - 1)*((x*y + 2*z)*((2*x + y*z)*(y + z + 1) - (x*y + 2*z)*(x + y + 1)) + (x*z + 2*y)*((x*y + 2*z)*(x + z + 1) - (x**2 + z**2 + 1)*(y + z + 1)) + ((2*x + y*z)*(x + z + 1) - (x + y + 1)*(x**2 + z**2 + 1))*(-y**2 - z**2 - 1)) + (x**2 + y**2 + 1)*((-x*y - 2*z)*(3*x*y + 6*z - (x + z + 1)*(y + z + 1)) + ((x*y + 2*z)*(x + z + 1) - (x**2 + z**2 + 1)*(y + z + 1))*(y + z + 1) + (y**2 + z**2 + 1)*(3*x**2 + 3*z**2 - (x + z + 1)**2 + 3))
```

and if I assign this expression for example in [SymPy Live](https://live.sympy.org/) to a variable `Dt` and enter

```
simplify(Dt)
```

I get the result **0**. Also if I evaluate the determinant expression with the actual values, the result gets closer to zero the higher the precision is.

`>>> Dt.subs([(x, 1.06273608e-01), (y, 2.12250279e-03), (z, 3.01468295e-04)])
−2.22044604925031⋅10−16
>>> Dt.evalf(subs={x: 1.06273608e-01, y: 2.12250279e-03, z: 3.01468295e-04})
4.0⋅10−127
>>> Dt.evalf(100, subs={x: 1.06273608e-01, y: 2.12250279e-03, z: 3.01468295e-04})
6.0⋅10−210
>>> Dt.evalf(999, subs={x: 1.06273608e-01, y: 2.12250279e-03, z: 3.01468295e-04})
2.0⋅10−2006`

[Wolfram Alpha](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=inv%20%7B%7Bx**2%20%2B%20y**2%20%2B%201%2C%20x*z%20%2B%202*y%2C%202*x%20%2B%20y*z%2C%20x%20%2B%20y%20%2B%201%7D%2C%20%7Bx*z%20%2B%202*y%2C%20y**2%20%2B%20z**2%20%2B%201%2C%20x*y%20%2B%202*z%2C%20y%20%2B%20z%20%2B%201%7D%2C%20%7B2*x%20%2B%20y*z%2C%20x*y%20%2B%202*z%2C%20x**2%20%2B%20z**2%20%2B%201%2C%20x%20%2B%20z%20%2B%201%7D%2C%20%7Bx%20%2B%20y%20%2B%201%2C%20y%20%2B%20z%20%2B%201%2C%20x%20%2B%20z%20%2B%201%2C%203%7D%7D) also computes this result `(matrix is singular)`. It does even say this for inverting every [matrix that is the product `VT·V`](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=inv%20%28%20transpose%20%7B%7Ba%2C%20b%2C%20c%2C%20d%7D%2C%20%7Be%2C%20f%2C%20g%2C%20h%7D%2C%20%7Bi%2C%20j%2C%20k%2C%20l%7D%7D%20.%20%7B%7Ba%2C%20b%2C%20c%2C%20d%7D%2C%20%7Be%2C%20f%2C%20g%2C%20h%7D%2C%20%7Bi%2C%20j%2C%20k%2C%20l%7D%7D%20%29), not depending on the element values of `V`.